# Docker - Cannot execute multiple docker run commands from same .sh file

Tags: docker

This is a complete Docker newbie question. I have a .sh file from where I want to invoke docker run twice. However only the first docker run executes, why?

```
mvn clean package docker:build -DskipTests
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile1" -p 8080:8080 -ti something/myapp
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile2" -p 8181:8181 -ti something/myapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are running the container with `-it`. This instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the container’s stdin and creates an interactive bash shell in the container. So when you run the first container the interactive shell blocks the execution of the second container.

Try to replace -it with -d which runs the container in detached mode. Please refer to this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/detached--d)

```
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile1" -p 8080:8080 -d something/myapp
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile2" -p 8181:8181 -d something/myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -d to run containers in detached mode:

```
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile1" -p 8080:8080 -d -ti something/myapp
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile2" -p 8181:8181 -d -ti something/myapp
```

Comment: afaik it is not possible to run a container with both `-d` and `-it` switches.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.

Comment: By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits; so if container runs command /bin/bash , it stops soon. For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often written -it.